# Test case not passed using while loop in C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, testcase

**My Need:**

Using a while loop greet as many names as that are available on the stdin. Stop when you read the string '42' as a name.

**My Coding:**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int input=1;
    int i= 0;
    string name;
    while(input<=i)
    {
        cin>>name;
        if(name=="42")
        {
             break;
        }
        else
        {
           cout<<"Hello "<<name<<"!";
           i++;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Result:**

For input 42, test case is passed. For other input, test case failed. Please post your answer.

**Answer After ~1 Year:**

Very sorry for this question . This is I asked when I have 0 knowledge about C++. This may be useful for the freshers.

Comment: Are you sure your code enters the loop?

Comment: You never enter the `while` loop. The condition in it is always false. Why not using a debugger first?

Answer (score 5):

Your loop is flawed

```
int input=1;
int i= 0;
string name;
while(input<=i)
```

as `input` is greater than `i` to start with

You **think** the test case works for 42 but actually the logic inside your loop is never executed. It is simply the case that the console output is the same (i.e. there is none) but your code never gets as far as the `cin` to check the input is 42

Comment: I got output sir. I need to put 1 in while condition. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't ever enter `while` since the condition is always `false`.

Just use,

```
....
while(1)
{
....
```

This will run your loop indefinitely, and break whenever 42 is encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not even run when you pass 42, because `input` is greater than `i`.

```
while(input<=i) // input = 1, i = 0, 1 > 0
```

What you probably want is an infinite loop:

```
while (true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code has these Problems:

- It won't enter the while loop as *input* is initialized to 1 and *i* is initialized to 0.While checking the condition *while(input<=i)*i.e., *while(1<=0)* which is false it won't execute the statements below.
  -

My Solution:

```
 #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int input=0;
int i= 1;
string name;
while(input<=i)
{
    cin>>name;
    if(name=="42")
    {
         break;
    }
    else
    {
       cout<<"Hello "<<name<<"!";
       i++;
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

- Initializing *input* with 0 and *i* with 1 will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Sorry for my basic question. The loop is not initiated. Because the `input` is 1 and `i` is 0. But the condition I given is `input<=i`. Because of the false condition, the control is not entering in loop